# Winrt scrollviewer different behavior in simulator as mouse or finger

Tags: pointers, windows-runtime, mouse, scrollviewer

I have a grid with some controls and Background. Inside the grid is also a canvas over the complete grid. On pointer_pressed I paint on the canvas. Works very well in simulator with mouse and finger. If I add a scrollviewer everything looks like expected and the painting works very well with mouse and the moving with the scrollbars works also very well, but on finger it moves the content of the scrollviewer and does not paint. So the behavior is different. For my needs it would be great If I can change the behavior only for these scrollviewer that the finger works like the mouse. Is that in winrt possible?

Comment: Well, when do you know, that you want to scroll instead of painting? It's currently the same gesture.

Comment: Hello,ith mouse I point to the scrollbars

Comment: Hello Raubi, with mouse I point to the scrollbars and scroll. Is the mouse over the canvas I paint, with the finger it scrolls always. I hoped that there is a method that the behavior is always like mouse, independent from the finger, mouse or anything else as pointing device. Basilius

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar before and could not do it. I would suggest implementing your own custom scrollviewer.

Comment: Hello Filip, thanks for the idea. Please apologise this question, but how you have down this? Basilius

Comment: You can start with that SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636216/scrollviewer-and-handling-manipulation-events-on-child-elements/12647796#12647796

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years ago but I ran into this today and wanted to chime in. I have a touch drawing canvas in a scrollviewer. I decided while the ink canvas had the focus to disable the scrollviewer.

XAML

```
< Canvas x:Name="InkCanvas" Background="White" Height="100" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" PointerEntered="CanvasGotFocus" PointerExited="CanvasLostFocus" />
```

C#

```
private void CanvasGotFocus(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        scroller.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
    }

    private void CanvasLostFocus(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        scroller.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    }
```