# How to detect when a user pulls down a ListView

Tags: windows-runtime

I want to implement pull to refresh in a Windows Store App. When the user pulls down the list beyond the top of the list, I want to show a message and some animation.

Is there a way to hook into the `PointerMoved` event when the user is pulling down the list? I do not get this event when the user is pulling.

I tried to get it on one of the descendants of the ListView. There I can get it during pulling when I set `ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All`, but then the list is not scrolling anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could figure it out was to implement my own ListView/ScrollViewer input. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636216/scrollviewer-and-handling-manipulation-events-on-child-elements).