# Pull To Refresh in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

Is there any SDK or frameworks to realise 'Pull To Refresh' feature in Windows Store App?
[image]

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: NO, i just asked the question

Comment: google.com is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize on your own. There's no 3rd party UI control till now available for WinRT. This might help you.

[How to detect when a user pulls down a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028302/how-to-detect-when-a-user-pulls-down-a-listview)