# WinRT ScrollViewer inheritance

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, scrollviewer

I have an issue with the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer`.

It does not work as I'd like it to (*doh*). If I put a Canvas inside and want to draw on it I can't as all the events from Canvas are passed down to the ScrollViewer.
 So my solution to the problem would be rather simple if I could have controlled what goes on in the ScrollViewer when the event is received (ditch it, pass it to Canvas, call the base for zoom, etc.) - but it seems like I can't do this as the `ScrollViewer` is **sealed class**.

This would work in WPF but does not work in XAML.

Any ideas out there how to solve this rather stupid issue?

The only thing I can come up right now is to ditch the `ScrollViewer` and implement my own zoom and scroll functions on the Canvas class. :\ Would like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options - implement your own ScrollViewer or put something transparent over the ScrollViewer to handle the touch events. See these related questions:

[ScrollViewer and handling manipulation events on child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636216/scrollviewer-and-handling-manipulation-events-on-child-elements)

[How to allow manipulations within ListView/GridView Item controls while allowing scroll and cross-slide manipulations on the ListView/GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153038/how-to-allow-manipulations-within-listview-gridview-item-controls-while-allowing/14161596#14161596)

Comment: Didn't know about the manipulation modes and what they do. This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!