# ManipulationDelta event suppressed by ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a Windows Phone application with custom UI actions started by manipulation event. Unfortunately, *ScrollViewer* element is blocking all these events.

Example XAML:

```
<Grid Width="200" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="Grid_ManipulationCompleted" Background="Gray">
    <ScrollViewer ManipulationMode="TranslateY" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" Height="200">
        <Grid Height="400" Background="CadetBlue" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

C# code-behind:

```
private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e) {
    (sender as Grid).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver);
}

private void Grid_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    (sender as Grid).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
}
```

The example contains one gray rectangle and one blue square. The gray rectangle is the element I want to manipulate. If it is manipulated, it changes its color to silver. The blue square is *ScrollViewer* which blocks horizontal manipulation despite *HorizontalScrollMode* is disabled.

How can I force the *ScrollViewer* to ignore horizontal manipulation?

Comment: You may need to check out HorizontalScrollChaining and make sure it's enabled. Also, is there a reason that you can't combine the two into one control which tracks both X and Y?

Comment: I need also a UI virtualization. I cannot figure out how to combine virtualizing element and manual scrolling.

Comment: If you need virtualization, why not use a ListView? You can style it so there's no selection or highlight/hinting, and it will come with virtualization and scrolling.

Comment: ListView or GridView blocks manipulation events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow manipulations within ListView/GridView Item controls while allowing scroll and cross-slide manipulations on the ListView/GridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153038/how-to-allow-manipulations-within-listview-gridview-item-controls-while-allowing)