# Manipulation Grid with scrollviewer inside

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, gesture, scrollviewer

I have layout like this in my page.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="0,-30,0,0" ManipulationMode="All">
        <Grid Name="MainGrid" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grid}">
            <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False" >
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="Auto"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Scrollviewer just used for vertical sctolling. So I want to enable gesture manipulation horizontal in grid but it seems I can not get any gesture fired in grid. How I can achieve grid to make it enable manipulation gesture and scrollviewer just for vertical scrolling?

I already tried disable any horizontal scroll mode in scrollviewer and still can not get any manipulation gesture to be fired

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution please ?

[ScrollViewer and handling manipulation events on child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636216/scrollviewer-and-handling-manipulation-events-on-child-elements)

Good ref :

[How to allow manipulations within ListView/GridView Item controls while allowing scroll and cross-slide manipulations on the ListView/GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153038/how-to-allow-manipulations-within-listview-gridview-item-controls-while-allowing/14161596#14161596)